# My Home (~/) dir somehow got added as part of my git repo, now i can't remove it

Tags: git

I noticed that my `git status` suddenly includes my ~/ dir. When I did a `git add . -A` It included some files that were recently included into the directory. I don't know how they got there in the first place, but when i call `git rm --cached ~/` it refuses saying:

```
fatal: /Users/me/: '/Users/me' is outside repository
```

How can i get rid of this from the repository?

**UPDATE:** on request here is my `git status` output:

```
On branch temp
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/temp'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   gradle.properties
    modified:   gradle/plugins/idea.gradle
    modified:   gradle/plugins/info.gradle
    modified:   gradle/plugins/stage.gradle
    modified:   myproject.gradle
    new file:   ~/NewDir/my.ear
    new file:   ~/NewDir/build.gradle
    new file:   ~/NewDir/deploy-grenade
    new file:   ~/NewDir/deployment/install_template.py
    new file:   ~/NewDir/deployment/uninstall_template.py
    new file:   ~/NewDir/gradle.properties
    new file:   ~/NewDir/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
    new file:   ~/NewDir/gradlew
    new file:   ~/NewDir/gradlew.bat
    new file:   ~/NewDir/settings.gradle
    new file:   ~/NewDir/timestamp.txt
```

Comment: Can you include the `git status` output?

Comment: done. see the question

Comment: Do you have a ~/.git directory?

Comment: That doesn't look like ~/ is in your repo.  It looks like ~/NewDir is.  Also, since that's outside your repo directory, it's probable that it's actually a directory called "~", not the shell-resolved home directory.  Try "ls -d \~" or "ls \~" to see if you've got a badly-named "~" directory.

Comment: bahaha, turns out the '~' folder was a poorly named dir in my git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the directory '`~`' is actually a Dir under my git repository and not the actual shell-resolved home directory. Thanks `@Paul Hicks` for the insight.